# How to find if a 3d vector in part of a span created by 2 other 3d vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have 2 vectors: \begin{matrix} 3 \\ -2 \\ -3 \end{matrix}

and
\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -3 \end{matrix}

How do I check if vector

\begin{matrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 2 \end{matrix}
is in the span created by the first two matrices?

I have tried creating a matrix:
\begin{matrix} 3 & 1 & 1 \\ -2 & 0 & -1 \\ -3 & -3 & 2 \end{matrix}

and taking the rref but it gives me the a 3x3 Identity matrix. Please tell me what I am missing.

Comment: Just check if the determinant equals zero. Also, you made two mistakes in the last row of the matrix: should be $-3 \, -3 \, 2$.

Comment: Can I not solve it by using rref? Started by thinking if there was value of x1 and x2, where x1*v1 + x2*v2 = v3. Can I only do this if I have 3 vectors for t span for a 3d vector? This is what I was trying to do: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kzjVqg0Xxhk

Comment: Well, sure: it has given you the identity matrix, which is invertible, so the three vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: Ok, but the fact that each vector is linearly independent does't tell me if the third vector is in the span of the first two right?

Comment: It tells you that it ISN'T in the span of the first two. And is not that "each vector is linearly independent", this barely make senses (and if it does, it's in an obvious way). They are linearly independent together, as a set of three vectors in a 3-dimensional space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performing row operations (except multiplying a row by $0$) on a matrix never change any linear dependencies between columns. If the columns of a matrix are linearly independent after applying a bunch of row operations, then they were linearly independent before you carried out the row operations. And if you carry out row operations and the result is that some columns are linearly dependent, then they were linearly dependent from the start.

In the $3\times 3$ identity matrix, the columns are clearly linearly independent. So the original columns were also linearly independent.

If the rref had given you something like
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&2&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}
$$
then we see that the columns are linearly dependent, but the final column is not in the span of the first two. This result would carry back to the original matrix as well, giving you the result you're after in a case where the determinant approach would fail.

Comment: Why are we checking if the columns are independent? Don't we check if the rows (where one row represents one vector) are independent?

Comment: @KohmeiKadoya You're originally interested in the existence of a linear independence between three vectors. To help in calculations, you have put these three vectors next to one another _as the columns_ of a matrix. So linear independence between the columns is what we are interested in. Besides, row operations mess with the linear relations between rows, but if column 2 is twice column 1 (as in my last example), then row operations _do not change_ that fact. Relations between columns behave well when doing row operations, and vice versa.

Comment: Oh wow, I never thought of it that way! Thank you so much, this makes so much more sense.